# Create a named cell dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook with 3 worksheets. One worksheet will have input values (not created at the moment and not needed for this question), one worksheet with several "template" or "source" tables, and the last worksheet has 4 formatted "target" tables (empty or not doesn't matter). Each template table has 3 columns, one column identifying what the values are for in the second 2 columns. The value columns have formulas in them and each cell is Named. The formulas use the cell Names rather than cell address (e.g. MyData1 instead of C2).

I am trying to copy the templates into the target tables while also either copying the cell Names from the source into the targets or create the Names in the target tables based on the source cell Names. My code below I am creating the target names by using a "base" in the Name that will be changed depending on which target table it gets copied to. my sample tables have "Num0_" for a base in all the cell names (e.g. Num0_MyData1, Num0_SomeOtherData2, etc). Once the copy has completed the code will then name the cells by looking at the target Names (and address), replacing the base of the name with a new base, just adding a number of which target table it goes to, and replacing the sheet name in the address.

Here's where I need help. The way I am changing that address will only work if my template and target are using the same cell addresses of their perspective sheets. Which they are not. (e.g. Template1 table has value cells, each named, of B2 thru C10, and my target table for the copy may be F52 thur G60). Bottom line I need to figure out how to copy those names over with the templates or name the cells dynamically by doing something like a replace where I am incrementing the address value based on my target table #...remember I have 4 target tables which are static, I will only copy to those areas. I am new to VBA so any suggestions or help is appreciated.

NOTE: The copying of the table works as I want. It even names the cells (if the Template and Target Table have the same local worksheet cell address (e.g. C2)

```
'Declare Module level variables
'Variables for target tables are defined in sub's for each target table.
Dim cellName As Name
Dim newName As String
Dim newAddress As String
Dim newSheetVar
Dim oldSheetVar
Dim oldNameVar
Dim srcTable1

Sub copyTables()

newSheetVar = "TestSheet"
oldSheetVar = "Templates"
oldNameVar = "Num0_"
srcTable1 = "TestTableTemplate"

'Call sub functions to copy tables, name cells and update functions.
copySrc1Table
copySrc2Table
End Sub

'****there is another sub identical to this one below for copySrc2Table. 
Sub copySrc1Table()

newNameVar = "Num1_"
trgTable1 = "SourceEnvTable1"
    Sheets(oldSheetVar).Select
    Range(srcTable1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    For Each cellName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    'Find all names with common value
        If cellName.Name Like oldNameVar & "*" Then
      'Replace the common value with the update value you need
        newName = Replace(cellName.Name, oldNameVar, newNameVar)
        newAddress = Replace(cellName.RefersTo, oldSheetVar, newSheetVar)
      'Edit the name of the name. This will change any formulas using this name as well
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=newName, RefersTo:=newAddress
        End If
    Next cellName
    Sheets(newSheetVar).Select
    Range(trgTable1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated you copySrc1Table() procedure removing the find method on the line setting newAdress. I've replaced this with a string that is first set to the source cellname.refers to value. This value is sent to a new sub (sub UpdateRefersTo) which changes it's value to that desired and this is then used to set the newAdress value

```
'****there is another sub identical to this one below for copySrc2Table.
Sub copySrc1Table()
Dim trgTable1
Dim vSplitAdress As Variant
Dim sRefersTo As String

newNameVar = "Num1_"
trgTable1 = "SourceEnvTable1"
    Sheets(oldSheetVar).Select
    Range(srcTable1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(newSheetVar).Select
    Range(trgTable1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

    For Each cellName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    'Find all names with common value
        If cellName.Name Like oldNameVar & "*" Then
      'Replace the common value with the update value you need
        sRefersTo = cellName.RefersTo
        Call UpdateRefersTo(sRefersTo)
        newName = Replace(cellName.Name, oldNameVar, newNameVar)
        newAddress = sRefersTo
      'Edit the name of the name. This will change any formulas using this name as well
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=newName, RefersTo:=newAddress
        End If
    Next cellName
```

It does this using a case element, so for each address in the template worksheet you will need to write a case statement for what the test sheet named range should refer to. Not an elegant solution, but it should work. Of course you still need to change the functions in the new table, but that shouldn't be too hard.

```
End Sub

Sub UpdateRefersTo(ByRef sRefersTo As String)
Dim sString As String

Select Case sRefersTo
    Case "=Templates!$B$2"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$52"
    Case "=Templates!$B$3"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$53"
    Case "=Templates!$B$4"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$54"
    Case "=Templates!$B$5"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$55"
    Case "=Templates!$B$6"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$56"
    Case "=Templates!$B$7"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$57"
    Case "=Templates!$B$8"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$58"
    Case "=Templates!$B$9"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$59"
    Case "=Templates!$B$10"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$F$60"
    Case "=Templates!$C$2"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$52"
    Case "=Templates!$C$3"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$53"
    Case "=Templates!$C$4"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$54"
    Case "=Templates!$C$5"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$55"
    Case "=Templates!$C$6"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$56"
    Case "=Templates!$C$7"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$57"
    Case "=Templates!$C$8"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$58"
    Case "=Templates!$C$9"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$59"
    Case "=Templates!$C$10"
        sRefersTo = "=TestSheet!$G$60"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This should work yes but I was hoping for something more dynamic, considering my target tables are set and have a defined named range and will not move. Doing something like a "n + 1" type deal take each named cell and change the address of that name by say 1 row, or 1 column, or 4 columns even if depending on the location of the target table. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "RefersTo" is a string and replacing the sheet name is simple, but adjusting the cell address is not.

So I think your best choice is to change approach and build the newAddress string from scratch. You have to do some math to determine, for each named cell, the (col, row) position relative to the source table. Then you apply those relative coordinates to the target table, to get the absolute (col, row) in the new sheet. Then you calculate the newAddress string.

Here's the code that's working in my test excel:

```
'Declare Module level variables
'Variables for target tables are defined in sub's for each target table.
Dim cellName As Name
Dim newName As String
Dim newNameVar As String
Dim newAddress As String
Dim newSheetVar
Dim oldSheetVar
Dim oldNameVar
Dim srcTable1
Dim trgTable1

Sub copyTables()

newSheetVar = "TestSheet"
oldSheetVar = "Templates"
oldNameVar = "Num0_"
srcTable1 = "TestTableTemplate"

'Call sub functions to copy tables, name cells and update functions.
copySrc1Table
'copySrc2Table
End Sub

'****there is another sub identical to this one below for copySrc2Table.
Sub copySrc1Table()

Dim isrcTable1StartingCol As Integer
Dim isrcTable1StartingRow As Integer
Dim itrgTable1StartingCol As Integer
Dim itrgTable1StartingRow As Integer
Dim iColInTable, iRowInTable As Integer

newNameVar = "Num1_"
trgTable1 = "SourceEnvTable1"
    ' get starting coordinates of target table
    itrgTable1StartingCol = Range(trgTable1).Column
    itrgTable1StartingRow = Range(trgTable1).Row
    Sheets(oldSheetVar).Select
    Range(srcTable1).Select
    ' get starting coordinates of source table
    isrcTable1StartingCol = Range(srcTable1).Column
    isrcTable1StartingRow = Range(srcTable1).Row
    Selection.Copy
    For Each cellName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    'Find all names with common value
        If cellName.Name Like oldNameVar & "*" Then
      'Replace the common value with the update value you need
        newName = Replace(cellName.Name, oldNameVar, newNameVar)
        'newAddress = Replace(cellName.RefersTo, oldSheetVar, newSheetVar)
        'get coords of current cellName in source table
        iColInTable = cellName.RefersToRange.Column - isrcTable1StartingCol
        iRowInTable = cellName.RefersToRange.Row - isrcTable1StartingRow
        newAddress = "=" & newSheetVar & "!$" & ConvertToLetter(itrgTable1StartingCol + iColInTable) & "$" & (itrgTable1StartingRow + iRowInTable)
      'Edit the name of the name. This will change any formulas using this name as well
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=newName, RefersTo:=newAddress
        End If
    Next cellName
    Sheets(newSheetVar).Select
    Range(trgTable1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

The ConvertToLetter function has been kindly provided by Microsoft itself, look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833402/en-us).

My working test excel can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10259913/StackOverflow/q18364566/Test_18364566.xls).

Hope this helps.